# I want to replicate a block I saw on another website. I got HTML/CSS, but how to make buttons work? How to find the script the button triggers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I want to create a block on my website, similar to the one on this page: https://www.smartbuyglasses.com/designer-eyeglasses/Tom-Ford/Tom-Ford-FT5178-001-93517.html

The one called "Available Lenses":

[Available lenses block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhr7q.png)

I copied HTML and CSS, and it looks fine when I test it locally, but I can't figure out how to find and copy the script (or whatever it is) that is triggered by the buttons when you press them, showing images and descriptions corresponding to the selected lens type.

I see what this script does - it adds "active" at the end of the class name of the corresponding element, i.e. it changes the class, effectively revealing the element through the updated class' CSS.

But I can't seem to find the actual script (or whatever it is) that changes the class name, so that I could replicate it on my own website. I'm using dev tools in Chrome, and I searched all over the place, including the "Sources" tab which does show multiple scripts, but I can't seem to find the one that I need. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. Can someone help please?

[You can see my attempt here](https://available-lenses.tiiny.site/)

Comment: Hi Ann, welcome to SO! Just for my info: you ripped commercial code and you want ppl on SO to help you modify it for your own purpose? haven't you read the 'Copyright' disclaimer at the bottom of that page?

Answer (score 0):

You could right click and "inspect" the individual buttons looking for their ID and then search the JavaScript for that ID. However, the page appears fairly straightforward so it would be less work to just write your own script.  You might even find a frontend library like bootstrap to use as well.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do and I can't figure out how to find the JavaScript for the button. I've looked everywhere. And the buttons don't seem to have IDs, only classes. Here is an example: <button data-available-lenses-index="no-prescription" class="w-100 mb-3 btn btn-outline-dark btn-outline-hover-orange flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1">Non-Prescription</button> Unfortunately, I'm not a developer myself and don't have enough skills to write my own scripts from scratch. Can you point me in the right direction, where to look for the script for a specific button in Chrome inspector?

Comment: view the page's source code and then search for `.js` and you will find 17 external script files. You'll have to open all 17 of them looking for `click` events.